# How to recover lost files on lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, data-recovery

I have an old PC. I have changed Windows to Lubuntu about a month ago. And i know need to recover some files which i deleted while i was using windows. Is it possible?
And this old PC doesn't have access to internet, if possible how can i install required software on it?

Comment: @user535733 thank you for comment. I know, man, it is a big problem, there is some document i need, i have to recover, i have to find something

Comment: Start planning for "It's gone forever," as that seems the likely outcome.

Comment: I used to live in one house. About a month ago I threw out some papers in that house. Then I moved to a new house. Do you think I can get those papers back? If I so, you may also get your files back too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if possible how can i install required software on it?

No. BUT you -never- install software on a disk you want to restore.

> about a month ago

That will be impossible. There is only a small limited time after you formatted a partition that you can restore the previous state. One of the things you can not do is use a partition you want to restore. You used it for a month... the old system will be gone.

In the case you managed to avoid writing to those parts of the disk you need to restore ... the way to do this: download Ubuntu on ANOTHER computer and make a bootable live session, install [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) in it and then use that to boot from to scan your system. Always worth a shot but I seriously doubt it will get you your file back.

Comment: `In the case you managed to avoid writing to those parts of the disk you need to restore` what do you mean by this? I haven't used computer since the installation of lubuntu. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, If you installed lUbuntu a month ago and never used it it is probably possible. If you used lubuntu for a month... not really. In cases like this you need to be precise in describing the circumstances.

Comment: That's vital information that needs to be in your question. Very few folks go through the effort of installing Ubuntu...and then not using it, so this answer's assumptions seem reasonable.